# Why do I need to execute hadoop as sudo?

Tags: macos, hadoop

I want to practice hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed mode so I followed the Apache's doc.
So I've tried

[image: this].

And this is what happens... nothing

[image: this]

After a few minutes I tried to execute as sudo and it works.
Why is this? How can I achieve my desired results?
My hadoop is 3.1.1 and I'm using macOS 10.13

Comment: What is the error your are getting. If possible set the env variable `HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console` it will help you to see some masked errors

Comment: Even when I set it , I don't get any error.

Comment: is there any error you are getting? Try `bash -x hadoop`

Comment: I get : + HADOOP_SHELL_EXECNAME=hadoop
+ MYNAME=hadoop
+ [[ -n /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1 ]]
+ HADOOP_DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec
+ HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec
+ HADOOP_NEW_CONFIG=true
+ [[ -f /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-config.sh ]]
+ . /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/hadoop-config.sh
++ exec /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/libexec/hadoop-config.sh .                

There is no error it seems

Comment: Assumably, there is some file permissions issues you're having, but you should be running `start-dfs`, not just `hadoop`

Comment: It was just to check if hadoop is correctly installed. I have the same problem with start-dfs and it's not the only one I have... why hadoop is so complicated to setup ?